# Why don't I accelerate upwards due to reaction force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

Now I am standing on the ground and thinking that I exert a force equal to my weight on the ground. So as a reaction the ground also exerts a equal reaction force on me of the same magnitude and opposite direction. Both forces are exerted on different bodies. So why doesn't the ground accelerate downward and me upward? Why am I standing still not going upwards?

Comment: I would way each body has 2 forces, your body gets an up and down force therefore zero motion. The ground is also getting an up force from the ground underneath the ground and a down force from you.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Then how can I jump?

Comment: Your legs provide an extra force..... so now there are 2 forces again on your body, gravity and and extra strong leg force which will put you in the air for a brief time.